# Issue with masked input in jQuery datepicker in french language

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, maskedinput, french

I am using jquery datepicker which supports localization and masked input. My problem is specifically with french language and format 'd M, yy'. In french, short month names are as below:
    ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'].

I am not able to type accent characters for months Feb, Aug and Dec. All dates with other months can be typed properly. Even if I copy "Déc", I am not able to enter this value. Does anyone know how this can be solved?

```
Sample code in below link:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shahrashmi/mf19c2wr/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the root cause. This is mainly due to month format and masking for specific language. Month format is where user enters short month names, so masking used was 'aaa' for month. But this mask only allows [A-Za-z] character set. As french has accent characters, those were not supported in the mask. So, I created new mask definition "[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u024F]" and used it for month masking.

The answer is updated in the same fiddle.